# Usage of で in 〜時で

Tags: particles, particle-で

In the following sentence, what is the usage of the particle で?

> 彼は、先生と話すときと友達と話すとき**で**、ことばや話し方をうまく使い分けている。

Can で indicate time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this で is associated with the verb 使い分ける. ～で使い分ける means "to use (things differently) *by* ～" or "to use (different things) *according to* ～". This で before 使い分ける is interchangeable with によって.

- 自動車を目的で使い分ける
  to use different cars according to the purpose
- 気分で香水を使い分ける
  to use different perfumes depending on your mood
- 彼は、先生と話すときと友達と話すときで、ことばや話し方をうまく使い分けている。
  He uses different words and ways of speaking properly depending on whether he is talking to his teachers or his friends.

Similar で is found in 日付で並び替える "to sort by date".